# Localization and internationalization code for google app engine java?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, localization, internationalization

Is there a list for all of the i18n file suffixes that we're supposed to use for Google App Engine project written in Java? Preferrably includes region as well.

e.g. suppose i have an english `ServerResponses.properties` file. where is the mapping/list that says:

`ServerResponse_uk.properties` -> Great Britain (i almost confused for ukranian at first)

`ServerResponse_es.properties` -> generic spanish

`ServerResponse_cn_TW.properties` -> chinese, traditional

...

Comment: `uk` is for Ukraine, I believe. `en_GB` is for Great Britain English

Answer (score 1):

`Locale.getAvailableLocales()` will give you such list.

Run this to get the list:

```
import java.util.Locale;

for (Locale l: Locale.getAvailableLocales()​) {
  System.out.println(l.getLanguage() + "_" + l.getCountry() + " " + l.getDisplayCountry());
}​
```

Comment: what would happen if you had say... Portuguese for Portugal and Portugues for Brazil; however, you didn't have the generic portuguese? what would someone in a portuguese speaking region (neither in brazil nor portugal) get?

Comment: like, i see that there's `pt`, `pt_BR`, `pr_PT`. but if i only serve `pt_BR` and `pt_PT`, is that sufficient to every client who has their language settings to portuguese? which portuguese would take higher preference?

Comment: That's a good question, but probably I don't have answer. I guess he will receive default i18n, from file like `messages.properties`, so it's better to have a default for language also `messages_pt.properties` for such users. But it's better to ask here about this, maybe I'm wrong